# Does SSRS 2008 support the XML Datatype in SQL Queries?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an query that uses the `XML` data type.  (You can see the query [here](https://gist.github.com/989888#file_gistfile1.sql).)

Just to be clear that means that my query has something like this in it:

```
declare @xmlDoc XML
```

When I try to paste my query in as a Dataset for a SQL Server Reporting Services Report in BIDS (Visual Studio 2008) a dialog pops asking me to define my parameters:

[image: Define Query Parameters]

The problem is that I don't have any Parameters!  I define and use @xmldoc in the query (it runs with no issues in SSMS).

It does not really seem to matter what I enter here.  This is always the next dialog box:

[image: Error Message]

"OK" closes the Dataset properties and I get no fields setup for me.  "Cancel" gets me back to the properties to try again.  If I put in a query without the `XML` data type then it works fine.

I am stumped... I can only conclude that SSRS does not support the XML data type.

Is that true?  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove variable @xmldoc and use

`CAST(@DocParam as XML)`

in INSERT query like this:

```
; With c as(SELECT CAST(@DocParam as XML) DocParam)
SELECT  TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
        TBL.SParam.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value1,
        TBL2.SParam2.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value2,
        TBL3.SParam3.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value3,
        TBL4.SParam4.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value4,
        TBL5.SParam5.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Value5
FROM  C 
CROSS APPLY
 DocParam.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[1]/*') AS TBL(SParam)
        left JOIN DocParam.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[2]/*') AS TBL2(SParam2) 
            ON TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
               = TBL2.SParam2.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        left JOIN DocParam.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[3]/*') AS TBL3(SParam3) 
            ON TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
               = TBL2.SParam2.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        left JOIN DocParam.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[4]/*') AS TBL4(SParam4) 
            ON TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
               = TBL2.SParam2.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        left JOIN DocParam.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[5]/*') AS TBL5(SParam5) 
            ON TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
               = TBL2.SParam2.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Second option is to have 2 DataSets, first sets @xmldoc parameter value and second use parameter in query

An third option is to use stored procedure with all that logic inside